# How exactly should I use the Facebook User public_profile data for registration on my app?

Tags: php, android, mysql, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an Android application that has 2 modes of sign-in : 
1. Username and password registered using email
2. Sign in with Facebook.

Now I have the registration up and running. I have a php file that accepts user data including the username and password to be passed to my server.

I have also implemented logging in to the app using Facebook.

Now, I am planning that once I have logged in using Facebook I would get the user's data and use it to register an account for the user to the server. But I have 2 problems :

1. The data from Facebook doesn't have a password. Thus it will not be accepted by my PHP file. I also don't think registering the user without a password is an option.
2. What if the facebook username is already existing in the server? I am currently implementing that usernames should be unique in my remote MySQL database, should I change it or not?
3. What is the most recommended use case for using the Facebook data to register a user to an android app's remote database?

Thanks for the replies. Please state references and such.

Comment: Why register a user with username and password? Use Facebook for login instead

Comment: Because I want the user to be able to sign in even if he doesn't want to connect his facebook account to the app.

Comment: I don't understand. If the user logs in using Facebook he have already connected his Facebook account with the app

Comment: Yes, but in my database it requires a password variable to register him as a valid user. Or do you have any better suggestions to my regiatration?

Comment: Change your database so it doesn't require password